# How do you correctly structure a WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello I am building a new WordPress theme for general open release, eventually I will GitHub it so I want to structure the file names and folders to a good standard so everyone feels comfortable and can find stuff quickly.

I am not referring to the standard files in a WordPress theme such as styless.csss, header.php etc but the files you add and link from functions.php that enhance the functionality as I am looking for a generic framework/standard that exists for a good layout.

Some WordPress themes place files into folders for  /lib/ or /inc/ and /assets/ can any one tell me why is this done, what is the structure name?

Comment: It's for better organization. You segment function files based on type (i.e. navigation, initial setup, etc). Assets would group CSS, JS, fonts, and images into appropriate folders.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, there is no preset structure to how to organise your Wordpress theme files. Its on how you personally like to keep your themes structured in what you feel comfortable with.

So when people put these structures in place, it is simply to help them figure out where they are in the folder structure and to make it easier to join together files.

Everyone has their own personal way to structuring it, I have my personal opinion on it and I'm sure you will have a way in your head of how you would structure it.

I try not to go too deep into a folder structure with files unless necessary, simply because the Wordpress themes are almost always front end, with Wordpress core dealing with all the back end stuff.

I also like to keep my functions folder modular, in that groups of functions each have their own individual file that can be easily managed and then just need to be included into the `functions.php`

This is my usual structure:

```
../
/img/
/js/
../libs/    //used for including large libraries.
/functions/
../nav.php    //a single file which has all the function calls for the navigation
/css/
../libs/    //used for css libraries
../sass/    //used for sass files
index.php
style.css
functions.php
.....etc
```

Then within the `functions.php` file i will have something like this:

```
<?php
@include 'functions/nav.php'; // load navigation
@include 'functions/other.php'; // some other file to load
?>
```

Now this is just how I do it, there is no right or wrong way to do it, everything has their own way and everyone is entitled to do it their own way.

As a project does get bigger or from the outset it is meant to be bigger, then i would recommend really sorting how to structure everything and how everything likes dynamically, simply because it will be easier in the long run.

If you're only working on a small project which wont have large impacts on the admin area or has many options, then keeping it nice and simple will make it easier for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for that, I guess I can relax a bit now I know my weird sense of structure cant be trolled

Answer (score 0):

Hey if want to currently structure your WordPress theme

Then Please Check Underscore A Starter WP Theme.

Link- http://underscores.me/

it is very useful for making good and structured WordPress Theme.